# Editing a specific core data object in modal view

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Progressing in my Core Data learning, I'm now stuck on the following :
I display a list of core data objects in ContentView.
If the user wants to edit one of them, he long-touches the item in the list which pops up a context sheet with and edit button. So far so good.
The edit Button summons a modal view on which the editing will take place.

In the Edit view, I start by fetching the correct item through its UUID property that I had stored in UserDefaults.

I am able to display the item's name, but I run into an issue with its date (the item has an "eventDate" Date property.

The app builds, I run it on my device, but it crashes as soon as I try to edit an item. An error is thrown in my EditView code when I instantiate the value to be displayed by a picker to the event's date :[image: The error]

Here's what happens inside the edit button :

```
Button(action: {
      self.modalViewCaller = 1 // To tell the sheet which view to display
      UserDefaults.standard.set(item.identNumber?.uuidString, forKey: kactiveEventUUID)
      self.settingsModalIsPresented = true
                })
                 {   Text("Edit entry")
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                }
```

And the way I fetch the event in EditView :

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    // We get the event to be edited through its UUID :
    @FetchRequest(entity: Takeoffs.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Takeoffs.eventDate, ascending: false)],
                  predicate: NSPredicate(format: "identNumber == %@", UUID(uuidString: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: kactiveEventUUID)!)! as CVarArg)) var fetchedEvent: FetchedResults<Takeoffs>
        // UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kactiveEventUUID) as! CVarArg)

    @State var selectedDate = Date()

    init() { // This sets "selectedDate" to the event's value for the date picker
        _selectedDate = State(initialValue:  fetchedEvent.first?.eventDate ?? Date()) // The underscore is used here
    }
```

The project is available here if anyone has the courage : https://github.com/Esowes/RecentExp

Thanks for any help...

[Edit :] Trying the .didAppear solution suggested below, but can't seem to find a view that accepts .didAppear in my body :

```
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Airport : ")
                        TextField(String(fetchedEvent.first?.airportName ?? ""), text: $airportNameTextfield)
                        .disabled(airportNameTextfield.count > 2) // To limit the textField to 3 chars (IATA code)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.airportNameTextfield = ""
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "clear")
                            }
                    } // END of Hstack
                    Picker("", selection: $typeSelectorIndex) {
                          ForEach(0 ..< types.count) { index in
                              Text(self.types[index]).tag(index)
                          }
                      }
                      .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    //  Text("Selected type is: \(types[typeSelectorIndex])")
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selectedDate = Date()
                        }) {
                            Text("Today")
                        }
                        DatePicker("",selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                            .padding(30)
                            .labelsHidden()
                    }
                } // END of Form
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading:
                    Button("Done") {
                        self.saveEdits()
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // This dismisses the view
                    } // END of Button "Done"
                )
                .navigationBarTitle("Event edition")
            } // END of Navigation View
        } // END of some View
```

Comment: i have did exactly same in my sample project. I used an alternative method by injecting a data class in to both content view and modal view. take a look: https://github.com/nikhiljohn10/CoreData-MacOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchedEvent` is not available yet at `View.init` call moment, so instead use it in `.didAppear`, like below

```
// ... remove that init at all

var body: some View {
    Text("Any internal view here")    
    .onAppear {
        // assigned fetched event data, here it is available
        self.selectedDate = self.fetchedEvent.first?.eventDate ?? Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Asperi. Can't seem to find a proper view on which to assign this .didAppear. I edited my question to show my  var body: some View code.

Comment: @Esowes, corrected.. it is `.onAppear`, you can assign it to topmost `NavigationView`.

Comment: Done ! Worked perfectly.